# BRE how to match up to empty spaces at the end of line?

Tags: regex, sed

Below is my test case. I'm trying to match and print a string occurring after the first `=` ignoring leading and trailing white spaces. My problem is I don't know how to `match up to trailing white spaces or the end of line`. It seems it's working fine with leading but trailing spaces are somehow problematic. I'm guessing it's got something to do with precedence but I can't figure it out by myself:

```
echo "TITLE=  B=ack=To ian   " | sed -n -e 's/[^=]*=[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)[[:blank:]]*$/\1/p' | od -tx1 -tc

0000000  42  3d  61  63  6b  3d  54  6f  20  69  61  6e  20  20  20  0a
          B   =   a   c   k   =   T   o       i   a   n              \n
```

Interestingly if I put those spaces as spaces `__` instead of `[[:blank:]]*` the expression works but it's loosing its flexibility:

```
echo "TITLE=  B=ack=To ian   " | sed -n -e 's/[^=]*=[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)   $/\1/p' | od -tx1 -tc

0000000  42  3d  61  63  6b  3d  54  6f  20  69  61  6e  0a
          B   =   a   c   k   =   T   o       i   a   n  \n
```

Ps, I'm not interested in how to do it with Perl's regex or with other tools, I'd like to understand why is this happening.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `\s*` instead of `[:blank:]*`. `\s` does not only match tabs and spaces, but also new line characters. Check out [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes).

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to make my script POSIX compliant and `\s*` is not POSIX as far as I know.

Comment: Then try `[:space:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
echo "TITLE=  B=ack=To ian   " | sed -n -e 's/[^=]*=[[:blank:]]*\(.*[^[:blank:]]\)[[:blank:]]*$/\1/p' | od -tx1 -tc
```

Since the quantifier * is greedy, it catch all it can. When you write `\(.*\)[[:blank:]]*$`, since the * make the character class `[[:blank:]]` optional (zero or more), all characters are eaten by the previous `\(.*\)`

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, it makes more sense now but I'm still confused with how come the `[^[:blank:]]` works. I mean how does it know there's going to be a character there other thank `blank`?

Comment: @user3014381: it know nothing! You force the regex engine to find a non blank character.

Comment: I think I understand `.*` because is greedy forces to look for that character farthest on the right hand side. I think. I might be wrong. Most likely I am.

Comment: @user3014381: If you don't put `[^[:blank:]]` the `.*` match all characters until the end of string and `[[:blank:]]*` match zero character (since * means zero or more times). But if you write the `[^[:blank:]]` the regex engine is forced to backtrack character by character from the end of string until it find a non blank character.

Comment: I think we're on the same page now. I'm having an epiphany moment right now. I further optimised this line to be: ` echo "TITLE=  B=ack=To ian     " | sed -n -e 's/[^=]*=[[:space:]]*\(.*[^[:space:]]\).*/\1/p' | od -tx1 -tc` as at the end of it I don't really need to match `blanks` any more.

Comment: @user3014381: indeed! (Thanks for these two english expressions: "to be on the same page", "to have an epiphany moment", in french the equivalent is: "to be on the same wavelength", "to have a revelation")

Answer (score 2):

Issue is not with `[[:blank:]]*` but with `.*`. Since `*` is greedy, it matches trailing spaces also.

I would prefer using `[[:space:]]` in place of `[[:blank:]]`

```
[:blank:]   [ \t]           space and TAB characters only
[:space:]   [ \t\n\r\f\v]   blank (whitespace) characters
```

---

Try following `sed`.

```
echo "TITLE=  B=ack=To ian   " | sed -rn -e 's/^[^=]*=//' -e 's/^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$//gp' | od -tx1 -tc
```

Output:

```
0000000  42  3d  61  63  6b  3d  54  6f  20  69  61  6e  0a
          B   =   a   c   k   =   T   o       i   a   n  \n
```

Idea here is to perform substitution in two steps

1. remove string up to and including the first `=` i.e. retain entire string after the first `=`
2. trim leading and trailing spaces.